# Is there anyway to in jeditable to removing submit button when using select

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jeditable

Can you have a jeditable select that submits on selecting the dropdown (instead of needing the extra 'submit' ok button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have found a solution to this problem.

Knowing that jeditable will generate following html

```
<div id="status" class="editable_select">
    <form>
        <select name="value">
            <option value="Active">Active</option>
            <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        <button type="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have just added following jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function () {        

        $('select').live('change', function () {
             $(this).parent().submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

(see [jQuery + Jeditable - detect when select is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541267/jquery-jeditable-detect-when-select-is-changed))

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I added this function:

```
if ('submit' == settings.onchange) {
    input.change(function() {
        form.submit();
    });
}
```

Right before the line:

```
form.submit(function(e) {
```

And for all the selects that I want to be updated on the change event I pass the setting onchange:'submit'