# jQuery + Jeditable - detect when select is changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jeditable

I'm using [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) for in-place editing. One the controls I am working with has the `select` type. When a user clicks on the field, the following `select` control is generated:

```
<div id="status" class="editable_select">
    <form>
        <select name="value">
            <option value="Active">Active</option>
            <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        <button type="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to use jQuery to detect when that `select` control is changed, especially since it doesn't have an ID attribute.

This is what I have so far, but the event is not getting triggered:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#status select').change(function () {
        alert("Change Event Triggered On:" + $(this).attr("value"));
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

Updating to jQuery 1.4.2 solved my problem along with using Matt's solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll probably find its because the select field is been added to the page after it's loaded (and after your event bindings take place).

You can still capture change events if this is the case by using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#status select').live('change', function () {
        alert("Change Event Triggered On:" + $(this).attr("value"));
    });
});
```

Note that since 1.7 however, the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method is the preferred way to bind event handlers. The equivalent of the above is;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#status select', function () {
        alert("Change Event Triggered On:" + $(this).attr("value"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Got it to work, thanks. However, this event doesn't bubble in IE for some reason. Thoughts?

Comment: jQuery should make it so. What code are you using that doesn't work?

Comment: @Matt: I'm using the code that you provided - it works fine in other browsers except IE8.

Comment: @Matt: Updating to jQuery 1.4.2 solved my problem. Thanks again!